# Sikuli Script image click with toggle

Tags: python, sikuli

I am new to this so pardon my lack of knowledge.

I am trying to write a script that constantly looks for images on the screen and clicks them when they appear. In addition, I was looking for the functionality to have the script be toggled on and off with a keystroke.(figured this part out)
Problem now is it finds the images fine.. but the delay between seems like forever. The image is there for nearly 5 seconds before it see's it and clicks it. Is there any way to make it look for the images faster?

Thanks in advance!

This is what I have so far:

```
Settings.MoveMouseDelay = 0.0
running = True
def runHotkey(event):
    global running
    running = False

Env.addHotkey(Key.F1, KeyModifier.CTRL, runHotkey)
nox = switchApp("NoxPlayer 5.2.1.0")
while(nox.hasWindow() and running):
    if exists("img1.png"):
        click("img1.png")
    if exists ("img2.png"):
        click("img2.png")
    if exists("img3.png"):
        click("img3.png")
    if exists("img4.png"):
        click("img4.png")
```

Comment: http://sikulix-2014.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Answer (score 0):

1) You can tune the image search algorithm parameter in your script

`Vision.setParameter("MinTargetSize", 6) # A small value such as 6 makes the matching algorithm be faster.
Vision.setParameter("MinTargetSize", 18) # A large value such as 18 makes the matching algorithm be more robust.`

2) You can also use a timeout setting in your if condition. For eg. I've added 2 seconds as a timeout here

`if exists("img1.png", 2):
        click("img1.png")`